# How to create n subprocesses that add m elements to a shared list among all subprocesses?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to write a static method of `stressTest (int n, int m)`, which creates n subprocesses that add m elements to a `MySafeList` shared among all the subprocesses. The method must return false, if the number of elements added is different from the expected number (n × m), or if an exception is thrown during execution. Make sure your test fails with `MySafeList` not synchronized.

Then I tried to use a static list and create a thread table.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MySafeList extends ArrayList<Double>{

    static ArrayList<Double> mySafeList;

    public boolean add(Double d){
        mySafeList.add(d);
    }

    public int size(){
        return mySafeList.size();
    }

    public Double get(int i){
        mySafeList.get(i);
    }

    static boolean stressTest(int n, int m){
        Thread threads[] = new Thread[n]; //El nombre de tu variable se llama "threads"
        try{
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1));
                threads[i].start();
                for(int j=0; j<m;j++){
                    Double d = new Double((double) j);
                    mySafeList.add(d);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySafeList safeList = new MySafeList();
        stressTest(2,4);    
    }

}
```

Yet I get:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien\TD6_multi_threading>javac MySafeList.java
MySafeList.java:9: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
MySafeList.java:17: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
MySafeList.java:33: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
Note: MySafeList.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors
```

Comment: `void add(Double d)` ArrayList `add` return a boolean, not void, and you can't change the return type of overridden methods.

Comment: @markspace Thanks, I didn't knew

Comment: Method `add()` does not return a value. Method `get()` does not return a value.

Comment: @Abra Thanks, that what I was thinking at the beginning. Yet @markspace is saying that `add` return a boolean for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `stressTest()` is static. Class variable `mySafeList` is not. Either make `mySafeList` static, or make method `stressTest()` **not** static.

Also, `mySafeList` can only contain `Double` objects. You are trying to add a `int` primitive to `mySafeList`. You need to convert the `int` to a `Double`. One way to do this is...

```
Double d = new Double((double) j);
```